# How to make VLOOKUP() match with the next greater value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Please consider the table below:

[image]

If we write `VLOOKUP(12,A1:B6,2,TRUE)` we will get 2 as a result since the lookup value will match with 10 in the first column of the array and return the corresponding value in the second column.

What I am looking for is somewhat different. I want to find the value corresponding to the next greater value. For example, when my lookup value of 12, it will now match with 15
in the first column and then return 3 from the second column.

How do I do this preferably with `VLOOKUP` function?

Comment: Can't be done with `VLOOKUP`.  But the new `XLOOKUP` can, by searching from the bottom

Comment: @chrisneilsen, put it down as an answer? You wouldn't even need to search from the bottom, just for equal or next higher. `=XLOOKUP (12;A:A,B:B,,1)`

Comment: @jvdv. I don't have time at the moment to write a proper answer.   Feel free to do it if you want to

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel O365 with the `FILTER` function, and if your lookup value is in `D1`, you can use:

```
=MIN(FILTER(B1:B5,A1:A5>=D1))
```

If the entries in column B are text, and not sorted numeric, you can use:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B1:B5,A1:A5>=D1),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have O365 available then you can use the `INDEX`/`MATCH` functions entered as array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(TRUE,$A$1:$A$6>12,0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]